# time complexity is O(n)

Tags: sql

What is the time complexity of the following SQL query?

```
SELECT c1 FROM table1 ORDER BY c1;
```

I thought it would be O(nlogn) because it is a sort. But it turned out to be O(n). Is it because disk read is the bottle neck?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is O(n log n) if a sort is needed.

However, if an index is available then this only requires scanning the index.  That is an O(n) operation.

Comment: It might be useful to clarify what is meant by "available," as in the general case the index must also cover all of the selected columns.

Comment: @MichaelPetito . . . The index *does* cover all the selected columns.  The only column being selected is the one used in the `order by`.

Comment: Yes, in the example trivial query.  My comment is directed to someone who finds this explanation and may incorrectly conclude having an index on the sorted columns is sufficient.  (I've found this is a common misconception.)